# Okada-Schur functions and the Martin boundary of the Young-Fibonacci lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, infinite-combinatorics, potential-theory

This question is related to three earlier posts addressing properties of the Young-Fibonacci lattice $\Bbb{YF}$, namely:

[Differential posets, the Plancherel state $\varphi_\mathrm{P}$, and minimality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376320/differential-posets-the-plancherel-state-varphi-mathrmp-and-minimality)

[Young-Fibonacci tableaux, content, and the Okada algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278134/young-fibonacci-tableaux-content-and-the-okada-algebra/278564#278564)

[Infinite tridiagonal matrices and a special class of totally positive sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376942/infinite-tridiagonal-matrices-and-a-special-class-of-totally-positive-sequences)

According to the results of Goodman and Kerov, the parameter space $\Omega$ (as a set) of the Martin Boundary $E$ of the Young-Fibonacci lattice $\Bbb{YF}$
consists of: (1) an outlier point $\mathrm{P}$ together with (2) all pairs $(w,\beta)$ where $0 < \beta \leq 1$
is a real parameter and $w = \cdots a_4 a_3 a_2 a_1$ is an infinite fibonacci word with
$2$'s occurring at *positions* $ \dots, d_4, d_3, d_2, d_1$ when read from right to left
such that $\sum_{i \geq 1} 1/d_i < \infty$. Note that the *position*
of $2$ in a fibonacci word of the form $w = u2v$ is $1 + |v|$ where $|v|$
denotes the sum of the digits of the suffix $v$, otherwise called
the *length* of $v$. The reader should consult Goodman and Kerov's paper for a description of $\Omega$'s topology.

To each $\omega \in \Omega$ the corresponding point $\varphi_\omega \in E$,
is a non-negative, normalised harmonic function on $\Bbb{YF}$. Under this correspondence $\varphi_\mathrm{P}$
is the *Plancherel state*, i.e. for $u \in \Bbb{YF}$

\begin{equation}
\label{plancherel-measure}
\varphi_\mathrm{P}(u)  := {1 \over {\, |u|!}} \, \mathrm{dim}\big( \emptyset, u \big)
\end{equation}

where $\dim(u,v)$ denotes the number of saturated chains $(u_0 \lhd \cdots \lhd \, u_n)$ in $\Bbb{YF}$ starting at $u_0 = u$ and ending at $u_n =v$.

Recently Vsevolod Evtushevsky (see arXiv:2012.07447 and arXiv:2012.08107)
has announced a proof showing that the Martin Boundary $E$ coincides with its *minimal boundary*. If this is true, then any positive, normalised harmonic function
$\varphi: \Bbb{YF} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ should be expressed as

\begin{equation}
\varphi(u) \ = \ \int_\Omega  dM_\varphi(\omega) \, \varphi_\omega(u)  
\end{equation}

where $dM_\varphi$ is
a measure (morally a boundary condition) **uniquely** determined by $\varphi$. Because $\varphi$ is positive, normalised, and harmonic the map given by

\begin{equation}
\Bbb{YF} \ni u \mapsto \dim(\emptyset, u) \cdot \varphi(u)
\end{equation}

defines a probability measure $\mu_{\varphi,n}$ when restricted to the
subset $\Bbb{YF}_n$
consisting of fibonacci words $u \in \Bbb{YF}$ of length $|u|=n$
for any $n \geq 0$.
Presumably $dM_\varphi$ is constructed/defined for cylinder sets in $\varprojlim \Bbb{YF}_n$
using these finite probability measures $\mu_{\varphi,n}$. (I'm unsure about the exact relationship between $\Omega$ and the path space $\varprojlim \Bbb{YF}_n$ and any clarification about would be greatly appreciated.)

There is an alternative supply of normalised harmonic functions on the Young-Fibonacci lattice: I'll call them *Okada-Schur functions*,
but strictly speaking they are commutative versions of the polynomials defined in two non-commutative variables as introduced by Okada (Goodman and Kerov call them *clone symmetric functions*):

Let ${\bf y} = (y_1, y_2, y_3, \dots)$ be a sequence of real numbers.
The *Okada-Schur function* $\sigma_{\bf y}: \Bbb{YF} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$
associated to the sequence ${\bf y}$ is defined recursively (with respect to length) by

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\bf y}(u) \ = \
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
T_k ({\bf y}) 
& \text{if $u = 1^k$ for some $k \geq 0$} \\ \\
 S_k \big({{\bf y} + |v|} \big) \cdot \sigma_{\bf y}(v)
& \text{if $u=1^k2v$ for some $k \geq 0$}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
T_\ell ({\bf y}) = \ 
\det 
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & y_1 & 0 & \cdots\\
1 & 1 & y_2 &\\
0 & 1 & 1  & \\
\vdots & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{$\ell \times \ell $ tridiagonal matrix}} 
\quad
S_{\ell -1} ({\bf y}) = \ 
\det 
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 & 0 & \cdots\\
1 & 1 & y_3 &\\
0 & 1 & 1  & \\
\vdots & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{$\ell \times \ell$ tridiagonal matrix}} 
\end{equation}

for integers $\ell \geq 1$ and
where we employ the notation ${\bf y} + r:= (y_{1+r}, \, y_{2+r}, \, y_{3+r}, \, \dots)$ for any integer $r \geq 0$.
Okada proved that $\sigma_{\bf y}$ is a normalised harmonic function for any infinite sequence ${\bf y}$. It is not
clear to me what are necessary and sufficient conditions for $\sigma_{\bf y}$ to be positive, let alone non-negative for that matter.
There is, however, at least one case when $\sigma_{\bf y}$ is
positive, namely:

**Remark 1:**
Let ${\bf y} = \big({1 \over 2}, {1 \over 3}, {1 \over 4}, \dots \big)$
then $\sigma_{\bf y} = \varphi_\mathrm{P}$ (i.e. the Plancherel state).

Furthermore

**Remark 2:** If ${\bf y} = (y_1, y_2, y_3, \dots)$ is any sequence of real numbers for which $\sigma_{\bf y}$ is positive
then $\sigma_{{\bf y} + r}$ will be positive for any integer $r \geq 0$. (This basically follows from some of the observations made in [Infinite tridiagonal matrices and a special class of totally positive sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376942/infinite-tridiagonal-matrices-and-a-special-class-of-totally-positive-sequences)).

**Question 1:** Suppose ${\bf y}$ is a sequence such that $\sigma_{\bf y}$
is positive. Under which circumstances will $\sigma_{\bf y} \in E$ ?
My guess is only when ${\bf y} = \big({1 \over 2}, {1 \over 3}, {1 \over 4}, \dots \big)$ but what about ${\bf y} = 
\big({1 \over {r+2}}, {1 \over {r+3}}, {1 \over {r+4}}, \dots \big)$ for integers $r \geq 1$ ?

**Question 2:** Suppose now that $\sigma_{\bf y}$ is positive but $\sigma_{\bf y}
\notin E$. What is the unique measure $dM_{\bf y}$ on the Martin boundary $\Omega$ for which

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\bf y}(u) \ = \ \int_\Omega  dM_{\bf y}(\omega) \, \varphi_\omega(u)
\end{equation}

Again, what about ${\bf y} = \big({1 \over {r+2}}, {1 \over {r+3}}, {1 \over {r+4}}, \dots \big)$ for integers $r \geq 1$ ?

thanks, ines.

Comment: There were a bunch of glitches introduced by your edit for some reason.

Comment: sorry. For some reason, after putting the questions into quotation marks, some problems with the formulae appeared.